# Question and answer app using sirikit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sirikit

I studied and explored sirikit and it's category/domains like workout, photos, Ride Booking, Messaging etc.
I want to develop Inquiry base app using sirkit and for that I am looking for the domain which support my app requirements.

ex. KnowCovid19 is my app name

```
User says: "Hey siri, i want to Know about total cases of corona virus using KnowCovid19 App"
Siri says: "Okey, give me the country name"
User says: "India"
Siri says: "Thank you, select the state name, 1) Gujarat 2) Punjab 3) Maharastra etc."
User says: "Gujarat"
Siri says: "Thank you, select the district name, 1) Ahmedabad 2) Rajkot 3) Bhavnagar etc."
User says: "Bhavnagar"
Siri says: "Thank you."
```

so in above test case user wants to inquire about the total cases of corona virus and generate the report from KnowCovid19 App.

I would like to know is it possible to implement ? if yes then which Siri Domain best fits these requirements. Is there any Custom Domain I can use?
If you can share any reference links then it would be very easy for me to implement these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

SiriKit provides only a handful of supported intents and you cannot extend more than those. I don't see any of them fitting your requirement.

You could, however, add to your app some intents in Siri Shortcuts and then ask the user to manually associate your shortcut to the question they want. You can read more about Siri Shortcuts on the Apple Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app